# Creating recovery flash disk-on-key using recovery dvd disk for hp pavilion dv6510ej laptop

Tags: hard-drive, laptop, hp-pavilion

I have hp pavilion dv6510ej laptop and recovery dvd disk.

Recently I have to format all my hard disk so I lost my recovery partition.

I want to restore my laptop using the hp recovering dvd disk, but I can't because my dvd drive doesn't work.
So I tried to create a bootable flash drive using disk-on-key of 16 GB but didn't succeed.

How to copy my recovering dvd disk to a flash disk so I succeed to use  it for booting ?
Everything I tried doesn't work.

Thanks a lot

Comment: Order a set of recovery DVD's...http://h10025.www1.hp.com/ewfrf/wc/document?docname=c00810334&cc=us&lc=en&dlc=en

Comment: @Moab ummmm his dvd drive doesn't work, how would recovery dvds help...?

Comment: Buy a USB DVD drive, its the only way. USB recovery cannot be converted to DVD's.